# If $\frac{x^2+ax+3}{x^2+x+a}$ takes all real values, prove $4a^3+39<0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, proof-verification, quadratics

If $\frac{x^2+ax+3}{x^2+x+a}$ takes all real values for possible real values of $x$, then prove that $4a^3+39<0$. Here is how I approached it.

Let $$\frac{x^2+ax+3}{x^2+x+a}=y$$

Then, $$(y-1)x^2+(y-a)x+(ay-3)=0$$
We want all those $y$, for which there is a real $x$, that is, we want $y$ such that this quadratic has real roots. So, the discriminant $\Delta \geq 0$.
$$(y-a)^2-4(y-1)(ay-3) \geq 0$$

On simplifying, we obtain $$(1-4a)y^2+(2a+12)y+(a^2-12) \geq 0$$
We want to find those $a$ for which this is true for all $y$. So, the discriminant $\Delta \leq 0$ (so that the parabola never crosses the $x$ axis.) and $(1-4a)>0$ (so that it faces upwards and is always above the $x$ axis.)

This gives  $$(2a+12)^2-4(1-4a)(a^2-12) \leq 0$$
$$(a+6)^2-(1-4a)(a^2-12) \leq 0$$
which simplifies to  $$a^3-9a+12 \leq 0$$ which is not what I set out to achieve. Where did I go wrong?

And is there any other method to do this? (Perhaps Calculus based?)

Comment: The only logical error I can see in your argument, which probably doesn't end up making a difference in the result, is that you need to account separately for what happens when the quadratic term is zero, as the quadratic formula is not valid in that case. Your result is not necessarily wrong, as it implies 4a^3 + 39 < 0. The graphs of these two functions show this. An alternative method would be to say that since the function tends to 1 at $\pm \infty$, the condition will be satisfied if and only if: (1) the function tends to $\pm \infty$ (both) at some asymptotes; and (2) takes the value 1.

Comment: That idea would be based on the intermediate value theorem and the extreme value theorem. Also, you can simplify things by performing long division of the numerator by the denominator first.

Comment: You also need to think about the case of $0/0$.

Comment: @David I would need the function to be continuous in order to use Intermediate Value Theorem, but that is not always ensured, for example in the case $a=0$, it is not continuous at $x=0, -1$.

Comment: Yes, I know, but you would use the intermediate value theorem on intervals not including the poles. Say these are $e$ and $f$. It would be sufficient for the limit to be $+\infty$ to the left of $e$ and $-infty$ to the right of $f$ for instance. I'm realizing it may be a bit more complicated than I said, though, if the "outer" limits are both $+\infty$ or both $-\infty$. What I stated before is not entirely correct.

Comment: It does seem to be complicated, for me, and I would really appreciate it if you could show me how it's done. I'm not too proficient in using these theorems, though I understand most of them.

Comment: Probably, I should have said "a good deal" more complicated. When there are two vertical asymptotes, there is a lot of checking involved. In that case, the domain is divided into three intervals, and it might be necessary to find the min/max on the inner interval. I was most likely mistaken to believe that this method would be simpler than yours. To complete your proof, besides checking the minor cases I mentioned, all that's left to do is to prove that $a^3 - 9a + 12 \leq 0$ implies $4a^3 + 39 < 0$.

Comment: @David Okay, but do you have the link to some question on this site, or elsewhere **with solutions** that uses the method you were advocating? I would really like to see it in action somewhere. And about my proof, Yes, I can see that what I proved, implies the required statement, but it's not true the other way round. So, for example, at $x=-3$ though my condition is not satisfied, the required one is and the function does take all real values. So there is something wrong in what I did.

Comment: I don't know where on this site that kind of method is used for a function with parameters like yours. Basically you study the intervals on which the function is increasing/decreasing, and its limits and the bounds of those intervals. It's basic calculus, but with a lot of cases to look at due to the parameter. Your proof will be okay, because the question is phrased as an "if" statement, not an "if and only if" statement. And it works out that the cases where the function takes the form $0/0$ at least once are those where $a^3 - 9a + 12 = 0$, so that turns out not to be a problem.

Comment: I disagree with you when you say that if $a = -3$, all values are taken. Have a look at the graph of the function in that case. The value $0$ is clearly not taken. In fact, that is one of the problem cases that made the solution I suggested at first rather complicated. (The part in the middle has two limits of $-\infty$.)

Comment: Yes, I was about to say the same thing. I made a mistake, infact I didn't. My condition, it appears, is the correct one and the required one is incorrect, as you can see from the graph here https://www.desmos.com/calculator/x7kghrtaya

Comment: Okay. Now you just need to pay attention to the problems with a $0/0$ form and/or "quadratic" functions that turn out not to be quadratic because of a zero leading coefficient.

Comment: @David So, I presume this question makes no sense and I'll remove it. Thanks for all your help. And I don't need the question (that I asked you about) to be about functions of this type. Any type would do, I'd just love to see Intermediate Value Theorem being used to tackle questions about range or functions. Do you know of such questions?

Comment: Since the question is "if" and not "if and only if", it is possible that there's a very simple argument we're missing that gives the result directly. I'm looking for questions using the IVT.

Comment: Here is an example: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/851424/finding-the-range-and-domain-of-fx-tan-x/851433#851433 The general method to find the range of a continuous function on an interval $(a,b)$ is to find the intervals of increase and decrease, and the limits at $a^{+}$ and $b^{-}$. Then apply the intermediate value theorem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would argue that $4a^3+39<0$ is wrong, for example $a=-3$ satisfies it, however [the function](http://www.wolframalpha.com/share/clip?f=d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427epmfob2kjt), that follows from that value for $a$, does not span all real numbers.

First note that both the numerator and the denominator of the given function are polynomials of order two, with the same coefficients, which means that both limits of $x$ to plus or minus infinity will go to 1. So in order for the function to go to $\pm\infty$ the denominator has to become zero, so the poles of the function have to have real solutions

$$
x=\frac{-1\pm\sqrt{1-4a}}{2}\to a\leq\frac{1}{4}.
$$

In order for the function to be equal to zero the numerator has to become zero, so the zeros of the function have to have real solutions

$$
x=\frac{-a\pm\sqrt{a^2-12}}{2}\to a^2\geq 12.
$$

Combining these two constraints for $a$ yields

$$
a\leq-2\sqrt{3}.
$$

This does not yet ensure that the function covers all real values, namely one of the zeros has to lie between the two poles, such that the function will span all real numbers between the two poles (it will either go from $-\infty$ to $\infty$ or the other way around). Solving this does indeed yield $a^3-9a+12\leq 0$.

So your solution is correct and the given answer (partially) incorrect. Namely when your implicit solution is true, then the given implicit relation is also true. Because for real values of $a$, then your solution can also be approximated as $a\leq-3.5223$ and the given relation as $a<-2.1363$.

Comment: The question appears to have been phrased in the form of an implication, not an equivalence. Your argument doesn't contradict the statement of the question.

Comment: @fibonatic How do you conclude that the function goes to both $+\infty$ and $-\infty$ at the poles? Might they not go to $+\infty$ at both poles? (when $a= {1 \over 4}$)

Comment: @AritraDas Between the two poles the denominator will be negative, so if the numerator stays positive over that interval, then the function will come from  and go to $-\infty$ at that interval between the poles. However if the numerator changes sign in that interval (also crossing zero) then one of the two infinities will then become positive.

Comment: I get it now. Since at poles the function changes sign without giong through 0 and at zeroes it changes sign by going through 0, the sufficient condition to have a continuous stretch of $-\infty, 0, \infty$ is to have a zero between 2 poles, in this case. Thanks.